# Override binding of Authentication class in Shiro with Guice

Tags: angularjs, web-services, guice, shiro

The problem I encountered is connected with message of a type:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

So basically it is an issue of our Angular JS 1.4.3 frontend sending `OPTIONS` request to the server **before** actual request. Problem occurs, because there is no way to add authentication data to this request and it is being blocked by Apache Shiro as it tries to access protected address.

Since I can not fix it on Angular side, I thought it would be easy on the server side. Would be, but we use **Guice 4**.

In Guice config we properly set up Shiro:

```
install(new EEShiroModule(getServletContext()));
filter("/services/*").through(GuiceShiroFilter.class);
```

so far so good. But now I want to make a hole in the system, allowing the `OPTIONS` request not to be authenticated. I have found a similar approach here: http://blog.awolski.com/cors-dart-dropwizard-and-shiro/.

At the end I am supposed to *override* the `BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter` but it is not so simple as it would be in Spring or Ini configuration because I can not override class binding.

What would be the best approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Today I meet similar problem here. For CORS requests, the `OPTIONS` pre-flight request will be regarded as unauthenticated by Apache Shiro since the browser won't add custom headers to the `OPTIONS` request.

To solve this problem. I overrode the `AuthenticatingFilter`'s  `isAccessAllowed` method to make it always return true when the request's method is `OPTIONS`.

```
public class CORSAuthenticationFilter extends AuthenticatingFilter {

    @Override
    protected boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) {

        //Always return true if the request's method is OPTIONS
        if(request instanceof HttpServletRequest){
            if(((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod().toUpperCase().equals("OPTIONS")){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return  super.isAccessAllowed(request, response, mappedValue);
    }
}
```

If you are using `PermissionsAuthorizationFilter`, you need to override it too.

```
public class CORSPermissionAuthorizationFilter extends PermissionsAuthorizationFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) throws IOException {
        if(request instanceof HttpServletRequest){
            if(((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod().toUpperCase().equals("OPTIONS")){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.isAccessAllowed(request, response, mappedValue);
    }
}
```

After having these filters overridden. They should be declared to be the running implementation in shiro's config file.

That is how i get things to work. Hope it helps, a little bit late though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To be honest we are not using `Shiro` anymore so I can not test it. But - I hope one will find it useful!